# Strange error in trace file for NSAn standby process

Tags: oracle, dataguard, standby

One of the Oracle databases I help manage is the primary in a standby configuration, with two standby databases. I started finding repeated entries in the alert log on the primary for a failure to resolve the TNS connect identifier for log_archive_dest_3 and referencing the trace file for NSA3. That trace file had an error message I'd never seen before, and I can't find any information on it for the life of me: "LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_2 depends upon me, but my destination index 2 does not match its destination index 1." This showed up several times in the trace file.

I was able to verify that all standbys are up-to-date with the primary and are responsive to tnsping. Can anyone shed some light on this error?

Comment: Can you add more information about your configuration? RDBMS versions/editions? DG Broker is used? Any else information about the redo transport services from within the DBs? [Check Redo Transport Services in documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41134/log_transport.htm#SBYDB00400)

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, in MOS there's a related known bug with that message in 11.2.0.1 on Solaris (Bug 10331312)  and 11.2.0.2 on Linux x86-64 (Bug 14016842 , this one refilled for review) both referenced by Doc Id 1308804.1.

However it doesn't provides any source of cause. As workaround they recommend to disable the log_archive_trace parameter to = 0 (default), as those messages can be ignored.

Comment: Whoa, this question from 3 years ago was bumped to frontpage, and was never marked as answered. I would be glad to know if my answer helped you